# Needed help to build caml Query with multiple <And>

Tags: listview, sharepoint, caml, sharepoint-list, sharepoint-object-model

I am getting a query from list view by view.Query i got the following

```
<QUERY><GroupBy Collapse="TRUE" GroupLimit="100"><FieldRef Name="AlertGrp" /></GroupBy>       <OrderBy><FieldRef Name="PriorityNoLink" Ascending="FALSE" /><FieldRef Name="match_time"   Ascending="FALSE" /></OrderBy><Where><And><And><And>
<Neq><FieldRef Name="Category" /><Value Type="Text">ACH Alert</Value></Neq>
<Neq><FieldRef Name="Category" /><Value Type="Text">Check Fraud</Value></Neq>
</And>
<IsNull><FieldRef Name="Close_x0020_Reason" /></IsNull></And>
<Eq><FieldRef Name="AlertType" /><Value Type="Text">Alert</Value></Eq>
</And>
</Where></QUERY>
```

I want to add one more condition something like

```
<Geq><FieldRef Name="Created" /><Value Type="DateTime"><Today OffsetDays="-5" />    </Value></Geq>
```

I added after AlertType

```
<Eq><FieldRef Name="AlertType" /><Value Type="Text">Alert</Value></Eq>
</And>
```

and start tag < And> added in the beginning along with "< And>< And>< And>"

But showing wrong result. Kindly help me where i can add the new condition.

regards
jhanani

Comment: By the way, you can use "[CAML Builder][1]" to construct your CAML query :-)


  [1]: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72164/where-can-i-download-the-u2u-caml-query-builder-for-sharepoint-2010/72165#72165

Comment: After upgrade my version  now am able to get the correct lis view query.Now pls tell me where to add New<And> condition <QUERY><Where>And><Neq><FieldRef Name="Category" /><Value Type="Lookup">Check Fraud</Value></Neq><And><And><IsNull><FieldRef Name="Assigned_x0020_To" /></IsNull><IsNull><FieldRef Name="Close_x0020_Reason" /></IsNull></And><Eq><FieldRef Name="AlertType" /><Value Type="Text">Alert</Value></Eq></And></And></Where></QUERY>

Comment: Use Caml Builder to build your CAML syntax (see my previous comment)

Answer (score 1):

All your filters will be AND?

Try This:

```
<Where>
  <And>
    <And>
      <And>
        <And>
          <Neq>
            <FieldRef Name="Category" />
            <Value Type="Text">ACH Alert</Value>
          </Neq>
          <Neq>
            <FieldRef Name="Category" />
            <Value Type="Text">Check Fraud</Value>
          </Neq>
        </And>
        <IsNull>
          <FieldRef Name="Close_x0020_Reason" />
        </IsNull>
      </And>
      <Geq>
        <FieldRef Name="Created" />
        <Value Type="DateTime"><Today OffsetDays="-5" />
        </Value>
      </Geq>
    </And>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name="AlertType" />
      <Value Type="Text">Alert</Value>
    </Eq>
  </And>
</Where>
```

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply. just now i upgrade the site and got the exact query. Please let me know where can i addd one more condtion

Comment: <QUERY><Where>And><Neq><FieldRef Name="Category" /><Value Type="Lookup">Check Fraud</Value></Neq><And><And><IsNull><FieldRef Name="Assigned_x0020_To" /></IsNull><IsNull><FieldRef Name="Close_x0020_Reason" /></IsNull></And><Eq><FieldRef Name="AlertType" /><Value Type="Text">Alert</Value></Eq></And></And></Where></QUERY>                                                                where to add new condition "<Geq>
        <FieldRef Name="Created" />
        <Value Type="DateTime"><Today OffsetDays="-5" />
        </Value>
      </Geq>"

Comment: I got the correct query of list view now (after creating new site), kindly help me in the above query where to add Created codition

Comment: your query would be this: <Where><And><And><And><And><Neq><FieldRef Name="Catego
>Check Fraud</Value></Neq><IsNull><FieldRef Name="Assi
</And><IsNull><FieldRef Name="Close_x0020_Reason" /></
 Name="AlertType" /><Value Type="Text">Alert</Value></
me="Created" /><Value Type="DateTime"><Today OffsetDay
nd></Where>